# How to insert bytea value using postgresql-simple in Haskell

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I have a table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, val BYTEA);
```

Then I want to serialize my data structure with `binary` and store in the table, and then retrieve and deserialize back.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveAnyClass #-}
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Binary (encode, decode, Binary)
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data User = { name :: Text, email :: Text } deriving (Show, Generic, Binary)
main = do
  conn <- connect --...
  let encoded = encode User {name = "me", email = "me@home.net" }
  execute conn "INSERT INTO users(val) values(?)" $ Only encoded
  rs <- query_ conn "SELECT id, val FROM users"
  forM_ rs $ \(id,val) ->
    putStrLn $ (show (id :: Int)) ++ ": " ++ show (decode val :: User)
```

But I get error `Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 0: not enough bytes`.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

gives

```
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 | \x
```

I can't figure out how to map `ByteString`s to 'BYTEA`s. According to the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.4.0/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html) everything should be OK. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that the problem is with leading `\NUL`s.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by replacing the line

```
execute conn "INSERT INTO users(val) values(?)" $ Only encoded
```

with

```
execute conn "INSERT INTO users(val) values(?)" $ Only $ Binary encoded
```

It's because `toField(ByteString)` yields `Escape` whereas `toField(Binary ByteString)` yields `EscapeByteA`